# How is String in Java an immutable object, but I can still change its value after creating one?

Tags: java, string, object, immutability

How can this be if I can create a String, giving it a value. Then, I can simply overwrite its value like this:

```
String a="abc";
a="def";
```

How is it possible that I can change the value of `a`? I must be missing something here. I understand that Strings literals are used whenever creating a String object, rather than creating a new instance of String every time

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Sorry guys, this is a dumb question. I should've known now referencing works with Strings

Comment: No worries, but please do try googling next time (or, if you did, let us know what you searched for and why it didn't answer your question). I didn't remember the marked duplicate offhand, but a search for "java string immutable" had several highly relevant answers (including the one I marked this as a duplicate of).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your not changing its value you are creating a new `String`.  Technically your variable changes its value `(memory location its pointing to)` to reference a new `String` object but it is pointing to the new `String` object not the same `String` object.

You aren't actually changing the value of the original `String` object you are just referencing a new `String` so while the value of your variable does change you aren't actually changing the original `String` object...Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks! I get it now!!! Wow.. so simple, that I over-thought it.

Comment: @Kkronic no problem man glad I could help!

Answer (score 5):

```
String a="abc";//creating string literal object
a="def";
```

You are actually changing the reference of `a` to a new object created by the String literal "def".

`String` is immutable means that you cannot change the object  itself, but you can change the reference to the object. Changing an object means to use its methods to change one of its fields.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense now